# Is that possible to set phone number in checkout page?

Tags: magento2, checkout

In my module i am creating one customer attribute in that i saved customer phone number.

Now i want to set that number in phone number field on checkout page if there is no address saved.

is this possible to do? if yes than how can i do this?

**EDIT**

InstallData

```
$customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

  $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'telephone_no', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Telephone No.',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 90,
            'position' => 90,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'telephone_no')
            ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
            ]);

        $attribute->save();
```

EDIT THIS ONLY

```
 'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer','checkout_register','customer_account_create','customer_account_edit','adminhtml_checkout']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,it possible

At class of `Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\AttributeMerger` in function `getDefaultValue($attributeCode)` ,

and below code:

```
case 'telephone':
                /* add by Amit Bera */
                if ($this->getCustomer()) {
                    return $this->getCustomer()->getYourCustomfield();
                }
                break;
```

### **Edited:**

**You done the mistake,you need to assign that field checkout and other form where you need it**

```
 $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
        $used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
        $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
        $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
        $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
        $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
            ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
            ->setData("is_system", 0)
            ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
            ->setData("is_visible", 1)
            ->setData("sort_order", 100);

        $attribute->save();
```

Comment: When i go to checkout page its only show loader nothing else and its not giving any error

Comment: my customer attribute code is telephone_no so i write `$this->getCustomer()->getTelephoneNo();` but its gives this error Fatal error: Call to undefined method Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer::getTelephoneNo()

Comment: please use an static value at return  like `return  12233333` and check that value is coming or not

Comment: its throw a error `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer::getTelephoneNo()` how can i check?

Comment: again,i told you that add  return `123664`  instead of `return $this->getCustomer()->getYourCustomfield();` check that static value is coming or not

Comment: yes its coming..

Comment: What is your attribute code of that attribute?

Comment: its `telephone_no`

Comment: that mean your attribute does not configure properly

Comment: share ur installer code?

Comment: update my question

Comment: delete attribute run upgrade command but still same error

Comment: can yoy tell me why its not working?

Comment: i will check and let uy know

Comment: $this->getCustomer()->getFirstName()  is getting from `Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer` in that file they create method like getFirstName(),..etc so in that my custom field method is not existing so its throw a error...

Comment: issue is that your field  does available for checkout field map

Comment: I am accept this answer because its correct way to add, i need some modification that i will do it myself that, changes is i am getting customer id using this `$this->getCustomer()->getId()` and load it in customer model and get my custom attribute

Comment: i am delete that attribute and add used in form for checkout

Comment: on coming Sunday,i will write blog at my blog www.amitbera.com.Here i will fully explended,how you add  customer attribute at checkout and regarding ur question